# Program execution halts while loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, ssh, while-loop

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE
    do
[ ! -f /tmp/$(basename $0) ] && cp $0 /tmp/ && konsole -e $0 && exit
rm /tmp/$(basename $0) # open separate window for code to run
    $LINE << EOF # read line (ssh cmd)
    cd /st/task/ #commands during ssh
    ./start.sh #need something to let this run and go back to beginning
EOF
done < pdns.txt
```

so the start.sh command is designed to run continuously but it stops the while loop from iterating

Comment: `ssh` is probably reading from standard input, consuming the rest of `pdns.txt` before `read LINE` has a chance to run again.

Comment: thank you for your response however the problem as stated before, is that the start.sh doesn't finish by design and i still need to finish all iterations of the loop

Comment: Then run `start.sh` in the background. (`ssh`  reading from standard input is probably a problem you just haven't noticed yet, unless you've already configured it to read from `/dev/null`.)

Comment: is there another way? I have read that there isn't a goto command in bash so can someone show me another way because i want to see the output of the start.sh but i also want the while loop to complete

Comment: By "complete", do you mean you want multiple `ssh` commands running in parallel (each in a separate `konsole` window)?

Comment: yes sir exactly what i'm looking for!!! and also you have sparked my curiosity about what, in your opinion, i'm doing wrong here

Comment: What does `pdns.txt` look like? (Can you post the first couple of lines?)

Comment: ssh -T -i blah.pem ubuntu@blah.aws.com (basically the copy and paste of connecting to an amazon instance) for 11 lines for 11 instances

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this loop as follows:

1. Create an `ssh` configuration file named "aws.config" (or whatever you want; the specific name isn't important) that defines appropriate alias for each host, specifying whatever connection parameters you need.

   ```
   Host hostone
      User ubuntu
      Hostname blah.aws.com
      IdentityFile blah.pem

   Host hosttwo
      User someotheruser
      Hostname foo.aws.com
      IdentityFile bar.pem

   # etc

   Host *
       RequestTTY no
       RemoteCommand "cd /st/stack && ./start.sh"
   ```
2. The input file only needs the list of host aliases defined in the configuration file.

   ```
   $ cat pdns.txt
   hostone
   hosttwo
   # etc
   ```
3. Now the loop can simply be

   ```
   while IFS= read -r host; do
       konsole -e "ssh -F aws.config '$host'" &
       # If your version of ssh doesn't support RemoteCommand, use
       # konsole -e "ssh -F aws.config '$host' 'cd /st/stack && ./start.sh'"
   done < pdns.txt
   ```